# MySQL - what is wrong with this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running this query and getting an error:

```
select mst_machine.MachineName, 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(trn_dacs.DateTime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as dataTimeStamp,     
  trn_dacs.TargetWeight as dataValue, 
  trn_dacs.Weight 
FROM trn_dacs 
  INNER JOIN mst_machine ON trn_dacs.MachineNo = mst_machine.MachineNo 
where dataTimeStamp >= '1/31/2018 7:21:16 AM'
```

The error is:

> 1054 - Unknown column dataTimeStamp in 'where clause'

I'm not as familiar with MySQL as I am with SQL Server. I'm sure I've done this in SQL Server before.

Without the where clause, the query runs fine and the column header does show dataTimeStamp properly. (FYI).

Also - I know I can do this by substituting trn_dacs.DateTime for dataTimeStamp, however, I need to use an alias for that timestamp so that I can always auto-generate the where clause for any table structure.

Comment: This query will not work in any database.  You cannot use a column alias like that.

Comment: If you need to use an alias - wrap your query in another select and put `where` clause outside, that way you would be able to use inner alias.

Comment: Un-intuitively (although necessary for the db engine), the WHERE clause is evaluated before SELECT. So you can't use a column alias in the WHERE clause.

Comment: thanks guys.  That makes sense and I appreciate the tutelage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by others, you cannot use a column alias from the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause.

One hack you can use is to use a `HAVING` clause instead of a `WHERE` clause. This will not necessarily perform well (since MySQL cannot use an index to satisfy the filtering), but it satisfies your requirements as I understand them:

```
select mst_machine.MachineName, 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(trn_dacs.DateTime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as dataTimeStamp,     
  trn_dacs.TargetWeight as dataValue, 
  trn_dacs.Weight 
FROM trn_dacs 
  INNER JOIN mst_machine ON trn_dacs.MachineNo = mst_machine.MachineNo 
HAVING dataTimeStamp >= '2018-01-31 07:21:16'
```

Another option is to use the column in the `WHERE` clause, and apply a function to the timestamp you use for filtering. This could perform better since MySQL can use an index (if you have one) for the filtering:

```
select mst_machine.MachineName, 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(trn_dacs.DateTime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as dataTimeStamp,     
  trn_dacs.TargetWeight as dataValue, 
  trn_dacs.Weight 
FROM trn_dacs 
  INNER JOIN mst_machine ON trn_dacs.MachineNo = mst_machine.MachineNo 
WHERE trn_dacs.DateTime >= unix_timestamp('2018-01-31 07:21:16')
```

Comment: Query works, but doesn't truly filter out the timestamp it seems.  I tested this and still get dates from before this timestamp.

Comment: I'm going to use this method.  It does work, but have to make sure to format the timestamp in the same way as in the FROM_UNIXTIME.  So - as shown above, it does not work.  But if I changed to >= '2018-01-31 07:21:16' then it works fine.

Comment: I'll update my answer to use that date format for filtering, and also to give you another option that is less of a hack and could perform better.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use aliases in the where clause, use:

`WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(trn_dacs.DateTime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')  >= '1/31/2018 7:21:16 AM'`
instead of: 
`where dataTimeStamp >= '1/31/2018 7:21:16 AM'`

Comment: ok.  I have to change my core code around to fit this model. New answer above may fit better. Will accept whichever fits my code best. thanks.